# Build multiple branches at once in a YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have the following need: I want to produce/publish an artifact that is the result of multiple branches build.

Example: I have release/Update2, release/Update3, release/Update4, I want to build each of them to obtain Update2/Task.exe, Update3/Task.exe, Update4/Task.exe. And then zip them to release.zip.

I'd like to do it in YAML, but I can't find documentation saying how to build different branches at once. My other solution is to create a release pipeline on Azure DevOps, but I can't do it in YAML.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your yaml to build one default branch (like release/Update2). Additionally, add to yaml [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with `git checkout --force "your_branch"` and build steps. Consider using build templates to simplify your yaml file: [Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)